Why is Stochastic Gradient Descent valid?
It seems unclear to me why SGD/minibatch GD works. I heard from someone that SGD works because "as commonly seen in stochastic optimization, the gradient step is an unbiased estimator of the true gradient". I did not understand it. Why is SGD gradient step an "estimator"? What's the probability space here?
Previously, I always thought GD/SGD only has a purely optimization-based interpretation. I.e., given a fixed loss function with some parameters, we can argue analytically that GD/SGD will converge to some local minimum. I thought the only thing probabilistic here is that the construction of the loss function can be interpreted as MLE. However, I wonder if there's more probabilistic interpretation of GD/SGD. Is there a rigorous framework and justification of these "stochastic optimization" methods, or any references I should look at?

Your questions are addressed in the introductory paragraph of the Wikipedia article on SGD.
